# Trying to ssh into IPv6 address, getting "no route to host"

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, ipv6, openssh

I have a home computer that uses Ubuntu 22.04, that I'd likely to remotely SSH into, from the internet. I'm trying to do this through its public IPv6 address. The address doesn't begin with `fe80::`, so it's not a link-local address. This is the command I'm using:

`ssh <username>@<ipv6 address>`

However, it gives me this error: `ssh: connect to host <ipv6 address> port 22: No route to host`.

I'm able to SSH into this machine from another device on the same network using the above command, but not from the internet.

I also tried these variants, both giving the same `No route to host` error:

`ssh -6 <username>@<ipv6 address>`

`ssh <username>@<ipv6 address>%eno1`

What could be going wrong?

Ubuntu's `ufw` firewall is disabled. Also, this is what my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` looks like:

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

And this is what the result of `sudo iptables -L` looks like:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Your router probably has a firewall, too. But in the first place, does your client have IPv6? Also, note that unique local addresses are a thing.

Comment: Can you run a traceroute to the home computer from wherever you're trying to reach it from? Depending on platform, the relevant command might be `traceroute`, `traceroute6`, `tracert`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your initial question IPV6 routing works okay on your local network, so i would suggest checking out your firewall\nat\port forwarding configuration on a router, and maybe getting in touch with an isp, to figure out if there is anything on their side that prevents you from connecting via IPV6 externally.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

## `rm /etc/dhcpcd.conf`

I had the same IPv6 trouble on my VM, but then learned this one, little config file was optional.

[Dhcpcd // Gentoo Linux](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Dhcpcd/en) :

> All dhcpcd configuration can be set in the **/etc/dhcpcd.conf** file, but for most installations dhcpcd will work out of the box presuming most computers nowadays are behind a router or access point running a DHCP server.

The issue here is "over-configuring". If it works, don't make it over-complicated. KISS

---

*That may not be the OP's problem, but it was my problem, and I'm probably not the last.* Cheers!